# Extension of multiple entry Canada visa in old expired passport to renewed passport

Tags: canada, passport-renewals, visa-expiration

My ten year multiple entry Canada visa dated 20th Feb.2020  is valid upto 15th January, 2021 upto the date of expiry of my passport. I have renewed  my passport in December 2020. I want to travel to Canada in May, 2021. Can I travel on the old visa in my old passport  with renewed passport? If not, do I need  to reapply for visa?

Comment: If your visa, issued in Feb 2020, expires in January 2021, then you don't have a ten year visa.

Answer (score 2):

> valid upto 15th January, 2021 upto the date of expiry of my passport

Assuming this means that your passport and Canadian visa will expire on January 15, 2021, you would need to apply for a new visa.

Usually Canada doesn't issue a visitor visa beyond the validity of the passport. If the visa is expired, you cannot enter with it (with certain exceptions for study/work permit holders visiting US/St Pierre et Miquelon). You need to apply for a new visitor visa, but usually without too much difficulty barring significant change of circumstances (keep the COVID situation in mind, though).

If you have a valid (unexpired) visa in an old passport, you may use it with a new travel document.